# angular2: value not showing in the view - undefined

Tags: angular, angular2-services

So I am having a component and a service.... the service makes an API call and populates component's variable (this.data)

on the component side all works well, console.log on the strategic places always returns value... it's pretty straight forward

when I want to display the data (let's say just {{data.name}} in the View, I get an error... Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

this error is actually printed out before console.logs that I put in my service calls.... so I reckon it doesn't wait for calls to come back...

```
import { Component, OnInit }            from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES  }   from '@angular/router';
import { Index, IndexColumn }           from '../index';
import { IndexService }                 from '../index.service';

import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';


@Pipe({name: 'ex'})
export class StringifyPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: any): string {
        return JSON.stringify(value);
    }
}


@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'app-index',
    template: require('./indicesDetails.component.html'),
    styleUrls: [String(require('./indicesDetails.component.less'))],
    providers: [IndexService],
    pipes: [StringifyPipe]
})

export class IndicesDetailsComponent implements OnInit  {
    errorMessage: string;
    index: Index;
    mode = 'Observable';

    constructor (private indexService: IndexService,  private router: Router) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getDetails('AAAAAA');
    }

    getDetails(id:string) {
        this.indexService.getIndex()
            .subscribe(
                data => {
                    console.log(data);
                    this.index = data;
                },
                error =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error
            );
    }
}
```

ansd the view:

```
<main>
    <h1>INDEX DETAILS</h1>

    <h4>{{index | ex}}</h4>

    <h5>{{index.name}}</h5>

    <p>This is the home page</p>
</main>
```

if I don't put the line with index.name in the index get's printed out, index.name throws that mentioned error

Comment: Just for clarification. Are you parsing the api response to json object? Say with response.JSON() ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `index` is loaded asynchronously, so the property is null at the beginning. You need to leverage the Elvis operator to prevent from having the error:

```
<main>
  <h1>INDEX DETAILS</h1>

  <h4>{{index | ex}}</h4>

  <h5>{{index?.name}}</h5> <------

  <p>This is the home page</p>
</main>
```

Comment: OK, makes sense, but why is it not erroring on index itself?
or on the list page when I have a forLoop in my view, I didn't have to use the ? ... also angular1 didn't have to :)... just saying... not complainig

Comment: The problem is when you try to access a property of an undefined value (for example: index.name with index i's undefined at the beginning)... Yes agreed. It's not the case behavior as Angular1.

Comment: it's weird I haven't noticed that in any tutorials... well thanks, will try it on Monday... hope it works... I lost solid 2h over this..lol...

Comment: You're welcome! See this page: https://angular.io/cheatsheet (safe navigation operator)